# Trying to grab a specific element with css selector

Tags: html, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch.js and am trying to click a button on the date picker ui for jQuery. Obviously, depending on the day I'm going to run the test, the DatePicker UI changes.

I'm trying wrap my head around how I'm going to get nightwatchjs to click on the first non-disabled option (which jQueryUI presents as a link within a `td` element instead of a `span`).

```
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
<thead>
  <tr>
    ... Header
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>

    ... This entire row is disabled with td like this:

    <td class=
    "ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled class">
    <span class="ui-state-default">6</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class=
    "ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled class">
    <span class="ui-state-default">7</span></td>

    <td class="ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled class"><span class=
    "ui-state-default">8</span></td>

    <td class="ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled class"><span class=
    "ui-state-default">9</span></td>

    <td class="ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled class"><span class=
    "ui-state-default">10</span></td>

    <td class=
    "ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled class ui-datepicker-today">
    <span class="ui-state-default">11</span></td>

     // First instance of a clickable button that has an "a" element in it and this is the only one I want to grab:

    <td class="ui-datepicker-days-cell-over class" data-handler="selectDay"
    data-event="click" data-month="7" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default"
    href="#">12</a></td>

    <td class=
    "ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled class">
    <span class="ui-state-default">13</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

   ... Another row
  </tr>

  <tr>
    ... Another row
  </tr>

  <tr>
    ... Another row
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I've been playing with CSS to try and figure out what selector I can use to select the first `a` inside this table. I've tried these but it all grab the first `a` in the `td` because its the first child of that parent.

All of the following select all the links:

```
a:first-child
a:first-of-type
a:nth-child(1)
a:nth-of-type(1)
```

I've also tried a bit more specific:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td a:first-child
 ...
```

Still the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: I like how the mere passing mention of jQuery causes everyone to suggest using jQuery selectors, even when the library that's being used *isn't jQuery*. AFAIK Nightwatch doesn't support jQuery selectors or plugging Sizzle as the selector engine...

Comment: Does Nightwatch provide a way to perform commands on specific DOM elements? If so you *could* use jQuery to select the right element and pass its underlying DOM instance to Nightwatch. Otherwise your best bet is XPath.

Comment: Did you check the answers? Does it give the solution you were looking for?

Comment: Dekel , I don't think folks read the question clearly. I'm not trying to get an item using maquette selectors. I'm using a testing framework called Nightwatch JS and am trying to make it click the first available date using a CSS selector. So far the only appropriate suggestion is the one using xpath and it's not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few a hours of fiddling and research I realized that there wasn't an easy way of doing it using CSS selectors. Luckily Nightwatch.js allows you to use xPath.

You can easily switch between `css` or `xpath`. The following code works perfectly:

```
     ...
      .useXpath() // Switch to xPath
      .click('(//div[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table[@class="ui-datepicker-calendar"]/tbody/tr/td/a)[1]')
      .useCss() // then back to css
     ...
```

xPath provides a much richer, though a bit more complicated, method of selection. This was a perfect example of how using xPath is far more better than using the css selector.

Learn more about xPath [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp).

Learn how [nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org) uses xPath [here](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-xpath-selectors).

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these:

```js
  $( function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      minDate: new Date()
    });
    console.log($('#datepicker td.ui-datepicker-today a').text());
    console.log($('#datepicker td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable) a').first().text());
    console.log($('#datepicker td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable) a:not(.ui-state-highlight)').first().text());
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this two ways (using jQuery selectors):

Either select the first `td` that has an `a` - `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar td:has(a):first()")`

OR

select the first `td` without the disabled classes - `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar td:not(.ui-state-disabled):first()")`

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/g6c3uxco/)